# Automatic template argument deduction fails for return type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function

```
template <typename B, typename A>
B func(A x) {/*do something*/}
```

And in my code I am doing something like

```
uint32_t a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
uint64_t b = func(a);
```

But this fails with

```
test.cxx:10:16: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
  uint64_t b = func(a);
               ^~~~~~~~~
test.cxx:5:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'B'
```

So it seems that the type of `a` is automatically deduced but the type of `b` not. I can specify it (`uint64_t b = <uint64_t>func(a);`), sure, but why the compiler is not able to deduce it?

##### EDIT

Following comments also posting the content of the function (which is actually taking 2 other parameters)

```
template <typename B, typename A>
B bit_slice(A words[], int start, int end) {
  int wordSize = sizeof(A)*8;
  B s = 0;
  int n = end / wordSize;
  for(int i= 0; i <= n; ++i){
    s = (s << wordSize) + words[i];
  }
  s >>= (n+1) * wordSize - (end+1);
  B mask = (((T)1) << (end - start + 1))- 1;
  s &= mask;
  return s;
};
```

So basically a bit slicing of an array (representing something).

Comment: In your example there is no B to decuced since func doesn't return anything and to deduce a return type use auto.

Comment: You can change the return type to `auto` if the type can be deducted within the function.

Comment: what is `/*do something*/` ?

Comment: Edited so to give more context. I added the content of the function: a bit slicer of some arrays.

Comment: why is it a template?

Comment: The function is called in different places of the code for different bytestream types (`words` in some cases is `uint32_t`, in some others `uint8_t` and it will possibly be `uint16_t` in the future).

Comment: not sure if the code is correct, but `for(int i= 0; i <= n; ++i){` is unusual by using a closed interval. Usually half open intervals are used, ie `for(int i= 0; i < n; ++i){` and using `<=n` is usually out of bounds

Comment: The code is working. It's bit unusual indeed but it's working. Here in the bit slicing both start and end bits are included, which is probably even more unusual.

Comment: i wasnt sure about the asnwer I wrote. I now undeleted it again, but I still think that your approach is not right, because its just too easy to use this wrong. You seem to make some silent assupmtions about `A` and `B` and `start` and `end`, and when they do not hold you end up with undefined behavior. I suggest you to ask about the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than about this one detail of deducing `B`. [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: My curiosity was actually just on the deduction here but I appreciate your feedback. This version of the function is indeed not robust but in the real one there are checks on `start`/`end` and on the size of `A` and `B`. It's not perfect for sure but it's doing the job. I was just wondering about the possibility of avoiding specifying the return type in the template function call every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the argument cannot be deduced from `func(a);` then it cannot be deduced. `auto` return type can be deduced from the return statement, but not here. What you assign the return value to is not relevant. It simply doesnt work like this.

It does work however with a templated conversion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename A,typename B>
A the_implementation(B x) { return x*2; }

template <typename B>
struct proxy {
    B b;
    template <typename A>
    operator A() {
        return the_implementation<A>(b);
    }
};

template<typename B>
proxy<B> func(B x) {
    return {x};
}


int main() { 
    int x = 42;
    int y = func(x);
}
```

`func` returns a `proxy<B>`, `B` is deduced from `x`. Then `proxy<B>` can be converted to `int` via its conversion operator, which calls the actual function (because only now `A` and `B` have been deduced).

However, I have doubts that the above is a good idea in your code. Consider to write instead:

```
auto b = func<uint64_t>(a);
```